# Redirect clients through ssh tunnel to different server

Tags: debian, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, openshift-online-2

I have a Debian server, and an OpenShift gear.  To access the gear, clients need to connect to it with a SSH tunnel.  I want people to instead connect to my main server using a normal connection, and have my server send their requests through a SSH tunnel for them.  Pretty much, the request needs to go from

```
Client > Internet > Debian server > SSH tunnel > OpenShift 
> SSH tunnel > Debian server > Internet > Client
```

I could give instructions to the users on setting up the whole thing with PuTTY or something, but it would be over most of their heads.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be looking for proxy software for connecting to OpenShift.

```
Client --Internet-- ProxyServer --ssh_tunnel-- OpenShift
```

In your case, the ProxyServer would be your Debian server.

I have setup clients using keys to open tunnels with PuTTY.  It wasn't that difficult.